# microsoft bot framework passing value with card action

Tags: c#, botframework

i have defined the below

```
feedback.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {

            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(){ Title = "\U0001F603", Type=ActionTypes.PostBack,Value=$"happy"},
                new CardAction(){ Title = "\U0001F61E", Type=ActionTypes.PostBack, Value=$"unhappy" }
            }
        };
```

after action click it is going to the method

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;}
```

but the value in the activity.value is always null how to sent the value

Comment: What channel are you using? Card actions like postBack are handled differently on different channels, but a fairly reliable way to send metadata with a card action is to use an Adaptive Card's submit action so long as you're okay with the message having an empty text property

Comment: I want to send meta data only with SuggestedActions cardaction

Comment: Which channel is it?